# how do I filter properties from an entity using select() of Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, collections

Below is my DTO.

```
public class Product
{
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    //& so on
}
```

Method to get the list of products.

```
 public void GetProducts()
    {
        // below dal method returns collection of products. 
        // I am in need to select only few properties of the Product Entitiy
        var product = dalLayer.GetProductsList().Select(x => x.PId, y => y.Name)

    }
```

*I cannot filter the properties in DAL layer because this method is called from multiple places & different call require different properties.*

I tried below stuff.

```
  var products = dalLayer.GetProductsList().Select(
                    (x, y) => new
                    {
                        x.Id,
                        y.Name
                    });
```

But this also throwing compile time error

so How do I filter properties from product entity using `select()`??

Thanks.

Comment: You want to filter, why don't you use `Where`? It's also unclear why you don't use  `dalLayer.GetProductsList().Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Name })`. Both properties are in the same class.

Comment: Just a note when doing a Select you are doing a projection think of it as making visible, When using Where you are filtering.

Comment: You need to pass the filtering criteria in a `predicate`/`func` form which you can use in the `Where` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  the following

```
 var products = dalLayer.GetProductsList().Select(
                    pr => new
                    {
                        Id =pr.Id,
                        EndDate =pr.EndDate,
                        StartDate=pr.Startdate,
                    });
```

but note that you are creating an anonymous object

**Update**

Or if you don't want an anonymous object just create a view

```
 public class ProductViewDto
 { 
    public int  Id{get;set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime  StartDate{get;set;} 
 }

 var products = dalLayer.GetProductsList().Select(
                        pr => new ProductViewDto
                        {
                            Id =pr.Id,
                            EndDate =pr.EndDate,
                            StartDate=pr.Startdate,
                        });
```

Comment: Is there any way where I can do the same but with named object

Comment: yes but you have to create a custom dto just for this need

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to consume your suggested approach. I will mark your post accepted post to it. Also, can you please upvote my post if you find it worth??

Answer (score 0):

You could use tuples.

Before C# 7 [tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
var products = dalLayer.GetProductsList().Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.PId, x.Name)); 

foreach(var p in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(p.Item2);
}
```

Using C# 7. [C# 7 new Features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)

```
var products = dalLayer.GetProductsList().Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.PId, x.Name));

foreach(var (PId, Name) in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine(PId);
    Console.WriteLine(Name);
}
```